# How to call interface field referring generic type?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Here is the case.

I have the interface with the field:

```
public interface SpecificAction extends Action{

    String CONSTANT_FIELD = "Specific field";

}
```

And then I have the parametrized class with the method inside which I want to call my SpecificAction interface field:

```
public class Test<A extends Action>{

    void someMethod(){
        System.out.println(A.CONSTANT_FIELD); // there would be the "cannot resolve symbol 
                                              // CONSTANT_FIELD" message
    }

}
```

Is there any way how I can call that interface field referring to generic type instead of the interface?

Comment: I don't believe you can. However, you could make a method `A getConstantField();`

Comment: the fact that `A extends Action` of course does not mean that `A extends SpecificAction` (where `CONSTANT_FIELD` is defined)

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces define an "is-a" relationship type. They declare methods that should be implemented but not fields or any method-bodies.

What you need to do to get this working is to convert SpecificAction to an `abstract` class which may have default implemented methods and declare abstract methods (unimplemented).

EDIT: A solution (?)

```java
class Test<A extends Action> {

    private final A action;

    public Test(A someAction) {
        this.action = someAction;
    }

    void someMethod(){
        System.out.println(action.getConstantField());
    }
}

class SpecificAction extends Action {
    
    public SpecificAction(String constantField) {
        super(constantField);
    }
    
    // getConstantField inherited from parent class Action
}

// declaring this class abstract means it cannot be instantiated directly
abstract class Action {

    private String constantField = "UNKNOWN";

    public Action(String constantField) {
        this.constantField = constantField;
    }

    public String getConstantField() {
        return constantField;
    }
    
    public void setConstantField(String value) {
        this.constantField = value;
    }
}
```

If you call it from somewhere with something like

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test<SpecificAction>(new SpecificAction("SpecificAction")).someMethod();
    }
```

the output is:

```sh
SpecificAction

Process finished with exit code 0
```

i.e whatever you set the value to. You could refactor it to be constant within SpecificAction (a static final variable that gets passed to the super/parent constructor)

Comment: I've got SpecificAction interface inside another library and have no right to edit it

Comment: @Konstantin is a declaration like `public class Test<A extends Action & SpecificAction>` work for you may be?

Comment: check the edit above now.. is this what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your class from interface SpecificAction, not Action. Interface Action does not contains your field.

```java
interface SpecificAction extends Action {

    String CONSTANT_FIELD = "Specific field";

}

class Testt<A extends SpecificAction>{

    void someMethod(){
        System.out.println(A.CONSTANT_FIELD); // Fine
    }

}
```

Comment: Even though this works, it's deceptive. I'm pretty sure `A.CONSTANT_FIELD` will always resolve to `SpecificAction.CONSTANT_FIELD` instead of `A`'s own static field because generics are wonky sometimes.